# Max-width and background-size property

Tags: css, web, background

guys! I have, obviously, a problem. I wrote a page that have content generated from Sharepoint list. Its width can differ so I put `min-width` and `max-width` on parent div. Inside this div I have an empty div that has `background-image` and `background-size: cover;` set. Problem is that this image always show up with `width` size equal to that size set with `max-width` on parent div. Other child divs has that contain generated text show up with width appropriate to its content. Image div has `width: 100%;` set. Can you tell how can I achieve that this background image will fit its size to container width? Of course I checked and div with this image as background has correct width, but background overflows this div. Below I posted code for parent and image div:

```
 .page {
  min-width: 874px;
  max-width: 1200px;
  height: 800px;
  margin: auto;
  padding-left: 160px;
}

.upperImage {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  clear: both;
  background-image: url("imageUrl");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

Any ideas? I tried to achieve it using javascript and element.style.backgroundSize property but it didn't work, I couldn't even get it to return current size.

Comment: Can you make a demom I will help you.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B28EftY3TS4dcFQ5eEdoNVU4ek0/view?usp=sharing

You can see on this screen what I am talking about. It's hard to make a demo. What's weird that div with this image as backround has proper width and still background image exceeds its size.

Comment: But like this we can't really help you, I can't try different solutions or test something.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to give you some.